# ValueError when updating dictionary with list

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, updates

**No related duplicate found.**

I need to update a dictionary with a list (nested list) of length 2.
I expected this to work since the **Python docs** say the update () method may receive a dictionary or an iterable of **length 2**
https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update

Here's the code:

```
list1 = [['a', 12], ['b', 45], ['c', 7]]
dict1 = {}

#confirmation of length:
print(len(list1[0])) # prints 2

for i in list1:
    dict1.update(i)

print(dict1)
```

Here's another snippet which results to the same error:

```
print(dict(list1[0]))
```

So my question is why doesn't it work ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update all at once:

```
dict1.update(list1)
```

or unpack

```
for key, val in list1:
    dict1.setdefault(key, val)
```

Your first option doesn't work because you're trying update a list, your second because you're converting a list of values and not a list of pairs.

Comment: @SergeoPolo iterable of iterables of length 2

Comment: Would you mind correcting "dict1.update(list)" to "dict1.update(list1)" for future readers....

Comment: @SergeoPolo In light of the second comment, `dict1.update(tuple(i))` should work then.

Comment: @Guimoute where precisely ?   It doesn't work in the loop!

Comment: @SergeoPolo I think that was expected to make tuple with single element that is `i` but it actually makes tuple with the elements that i contains. You can do this with `dict1.update( (i) )` or `dict1.update( [i] )`. But that doesn't make logical sense because you unpack to pack again right away.

Comment: @miszcz2137 That's just an example of complying with the requirements of a function. We feed it the format it wants. Usually I try to support polymorphism in my functions by adding a conversion, say if you run a loop that does `for entry in entries: something()` I'll add a `entries = [entries]` beforehand if the entry is not iterable. In the case of `dict`, that support is absent.

Comment: @SergeoPolo Sorry not `tuple(i)` but `(i, )`.